# How to access temp directory of the local machine

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, tempdir

I am working on an application in which I need to open attachments. I need to click on the "Open" button and open a pdf file. The way I do it, is by getting the content from the Server and writing it to a location on the temp directory.

However when I try to access this service from a remote machine, 
http://myserverIP:port/openMyAttachment,  it accesses the temp directory of myserverIP instead of the local machine. It then opens the file on myserverIP.

I am using the following code to get the temp directory:

```
    String tmp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");      
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    FileSystemView fsv = fc.getFileSystemView();
    File f = fsv.getDefaultDirectory();
    String dir = f.getAbsolutePath();
    String strDirectory = "temp~" + f.separator;
```

Can someone please share your thoughts? How can I get to access the temp directory on teh local machine and write the file to the local machine?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do too much on the server. If you have a Java program running locally, then it should be showing the `JFileChooser`, then fetching the file, writing it to a local temp space, and displaying it.  The only thing the server should do is provide an `InputStream` to get the file contents from.  If you change your server to have a `getAttachment` query (or something) instead of the `openMyAttachment` query that just serves back a pdf file. Then you should be able to fetch it with a `URLConnection` and complete the work on the local computer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. new JFileChooser() is now throwing a null pointer exception. Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you show how the code looks now? Just calling `new JFileChooser()` should not cause an NPE.

Comment: Thanks for your response Steve. The code is the same as above. We did not proceed further and now we will start working on this module again. The problem is after fetching the tmp variable a null pointer exception is thrown.

Comment: The code in the original post could not throw an NPE in the second line. Do you dump a stack trace and the line number it's thrown on is the FileChooser call and there are no parameters?